# How to send data to new activity from current activity via intent?

Tags: java, android

How I can use the intent to send the data to the second class?

I am doing this actually

```
Intent connectGetData = new Intent(Main.this, GetData.class);
startActivityForResult(connectGetData, REQUEST_GET_DATA);
```

From `Main.java` activity I am calling the `Getdata.java` activity and I when come back I again get data using.

```
public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode, Intent mDataIntent)
```

Please tell me how I can send data to other activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pass data along with the Intent using two mechanisms, depending on the needs of your application.

1. The data field, via `Intent.setData()`: This is a URI that you can use to indicate the location of a resource the new Activity may need to use
2. Extras, via `Intent.putExtra()`: You can attach as many extras to an Intent as you like to represent the data you need to pass (both forwards to the new Activity and backwards with the result).  Extras can be any primitive or easily serializable object.

HTH

Comment: ok.for one value i can pass it. if i want to pass immedietly two strings values how can be done with putExtra()?

Comment: Call putExtra() twice, one for each string.  Each extra is identified by a unique key, so add as many extras as you want.  Just add each one with a unique key so you can get them back later with getStringExtra()

Answer (score 6):

At sending activity...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, next.class);
intent.putextra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

At receiving activity...

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Thus you can have data at receiving activity from sending activity...