# How to invoke getText() on the primitive type int?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use an AutoCompleteTextView suggestions to be clickable and brings user the another activity. And if anyone of you know how to work with an AutoCompleteTextView please head to [AutoCompleteTextView or SearchDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997684/autocompletetextview-or-searchdialog)

So heres what i am working with, other than invoking the getText(). Also how to define my intent below within my switch cases?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class Search extends Activity
{


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate)
    {
        final int autoComplete;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchshop);

        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompletee = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, shops);
        autoCompletee.setAdapter(adapter); 
        autoCompletee.setThreshold(1);
        autoCompletee.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
        {


                Intent intent;
                int index=999;
                for(int i=0;i<shops.length;i++)
                {

                    if(shops[i].equals(autoComplete.getText().toString().trim()))
                    {
                        index=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch(index)
                {
                    case 0:
                        //The constructor Intent(Search, int) is undefined
                        intent=new Intent(Search.this, R.layout.adidas);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        setContentView(R.layout.adidas);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //The constructor Intent(Search, int) is undefined
                        intent=new Intent(Search.this, R.layout.affin);
                        startActivity(intent);  
                        setContentView(R.layout.affin);
                        break; 
                }
            }
        });


    }
    static final String[] shops = new String[]
            {
                "Adidas", " Affin Bank", "Alam Art", "Al Amin"

            };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getText()` method on primitive types (or in general on reference types).  But I think that this should do what I think you are trying to do:

Replace

```
    autoComplete.getText().toString().trim()
```

with

```
    Integer.toString(autoComplete)
```

Comment: Okay, Integer.toString(autoComplete) giving me this. The local variable autoComplete has not been initialized. I would have to declare autoComplete as in static final int autoComplete;

But declaring with final is not permitted inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are trying to invoke `getText()` on int. To convert `int` to `String` you can use [`String.valueOf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) or [`Integer.toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29).

You should construct intents in another way:

```
intent = new Intent(Search.this, YourAnotherActivityName.class);
```

Additional reading:
[How to start activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity)
[How to pass data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090776/436938)